# Hibernate: what type of object after query

Tags: java, hibernate

How to get values from `List` element which contains `UserTable` and `ResultTable` data?

```
 List<?> list = hSession.createQuery("FROM UserTable u, ResultTable r WHERE u.id = r.id AND r.ispassed = 1").list();
 for(Object winner: winners) {
    // ...
 }
```

Comment: no, I mean how get class data i.e. what type of winner object is?

Comment: each table contains different columns (id, name, etc.), so how can we get that data?

Comment: what is ouput of `System.out.println(winner.getClass().getName()")` in loop? Is it `Object[]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get a `List` of `Object[]`, with each row having two entries - first one of type `UserTable` and second one of type `ResultTable`.

It would probably be faster for you to debug this on your own instead of posting a question.